# From where can I download SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010

Is there a CTP/Beta available? Do you have the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-register for the public Beta, which should be available around 18th November:

http://sharepoint2010.microsoft.com/try-it/Pages/Trial.aspx